# How I connect two waypoint systems?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

enter code here

```
List<Transform> points = new List <Transform> ();

private int destPoint = 0;
private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

public WaypointSystem path;
//Assembly-CSharp-firstpass
public float remainingDistance = 0.3f;

void Start () {

    points = path.waypoints;

    agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();

    // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
    // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
    // approaches a destination point).

       // agent.autoBraking = false;


    //GotoNextPoint();
}


void GotoNextPoint() {
    // Returns if no points have been set up
    if (points.Count == 0)
        return;
    if (destPoint == points.Count) return;

    // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
    agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;


    // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
    // cycling to the start if necessary.
    //destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    destPoint = (destPoint + 1);


}


void Update()
{
    // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
    // close to the current one.
    if (agent.remainingDistance < remainingDistance)
    {
        GotoNextPoint();
    }
   if(destpoint==8)
   agent.enabled=false;


}
}
```

I want to connect two wayPoint system. When a player(agent) reach to the last point of first wayPoint system it follows the second waypoint is it possible?
In the code, I disable the navmesh agent after reaching the last point of first waypoint system and after few second its get enable but the player return back to the first point of first wayPoint system it cannot jump to the second one

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with waypoint systems, but can't you just change your points variable to the new waypoint system's `waypoints` when you reacched the last point (it can be checked in `GotoNextPoint`.
Maybe something like this:

```
void GotoNextPoint() {
// Returns if no points have been set up
if (points.Count == 0)
    return;
if (destPoint == points.Count)
{
    points = otherPath.waypoints;
    destPoint = 0;
    return;
}
```

Don't forget to reset your `destPoint` to 0, so the navmesh agent will start from the first element of the 2nd waypoint system.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know what didn't work? Did you receive an error? or it produced different result? etc.?

Comment: Good to hear it. :) Kindly if my reply helped (or if it needs editing let me know) accept it as an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its only work when last point of first waypoint and first point of second waypoint system is near,any idea about that

Comment: What happens if they are "not near" enough? and what the "near" means in numbers?

Comment: if they are not near the player goes to the first point of first waypoint system

Comment: hm, that's strange. The code should work. I would advise to try to debug it and see what happens when the first wapoints end is reached. Let me know the result.